# A farmer sold a calf and a cow for Rs $760$. Find the cost of each.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, systems-of-equations

> A farmer sold a calf and a cow for Rs. $760$ Thereby making a profit of $25\%$ on the calf and $10\%$ on the cow. By selling them for Rs. $767.5$ he would have raised a profit of $10\%$ on the calf and $25\%$ on the cow. Find the cost of each.

I tried the following:

Let the price of a calf be $x$
Let the price of a cow be $y$
$x$$+$$y$$=$Rs$760$ $[\cdots (1)]$
Profit on Rs $x$$=$$x$$/$$4$
Profit on Rs $y$$=$$y$$/$$10$
Therefore, Total profit$=$$5$$x$$+$$2$$y$/$20$

I do not know what to do next.

Comment: Perhaps try $(1+0.25)x+(1+0.1)y=760, (1+0.1)x+(1+0.25)y=767.5$...

Comment: $[\text{original price of calf}] * 1.25 + [\text{original price of cow}] * 1.1 = 760$ is the first equation, where the original prices are the prices that the farmer paid. You can do something similar to get a second equation, and solve for the original prices. Then, multiplying by $1.25$ and $1.1$ gives you the price he sold the calf and cow, respectively, for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $x$ be the original cost (to the farmer) of a calf.

Let $y$ be the original cost (to the farmer) of a cow.

Then $$x + \frac x4  + y + \frac y{10} = 760 \iff \frac{5x}{4} + \frac{11y}{10} = 760\tag{1}$$

And $$x + \frac x{10} + y + \frac y4 = 767.5\iff \frac{11x}{10} + \frac{5y}{4} = 767.5\tag{2}$$

Now you can solve for $x, y$ to obtain the original cost of a calf and a cow.

If it helps you, multiplying each side of *each* equation by $20$ will get rid of fractions and decimals: $$25x + 22y = 15200\tag{1}$$
$$22x + 25y = 15350\tag{2}$$